# Spyder 4 is not showing Numpy arrays and Dataframes as before

Tags: anaconda, spyder

After I updated the Spyder to version 4, I can not use variable explorer to view the values of variables, only how object explorer. Is there a way to go back like older versions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) If you want to view Numpy arrays or dataframes with their specialized viewers, you need to install Numpy and Pandas on the same environment or Python installation where you installed Spyder.